# How to default open a CSV file downloaded from the website as Japanese (JIS) on window?

Tags: javascript, excel, playwright

I'm using PLaywright to download a CSV file from my website and save its data into database automatically.

However, after the download was done, I realized that all the data (Japanese characters) inside this file displayed wrong. So in my database, I get all the wrong characters.

Have any way for Playwright to read this CSV file as `Japanese (JIS)` instead of `UTF-8`?

**Note:** Because it runs automatically, I can't use the way that opens new Excel and use `Data > From Text/SVG` on the toolbar to convert this data.

Test file:

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

test('Save data', async ({ page }) => {
  const csvPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'csv', `20240218.csv`);
  const contentBuffer = fs.readFileSync(csvPath);
  const utf8Content = iconv.decode(contentBuffer, 'shiftjis');
  console.log(utf8Content);
});
```

Content of my csv file (UTF-8):

```
"���X�X��","���X��","��tNo.","���X�Ɋ܂�","�ڋqNo.","�ڋq��","�V�K","�ړI","���j���[�R�[�h","���j���[","����","���z","����","�v","�S����","�w��","�敪","����敪","����ŗ�","�w����","�_��No.","�����S����2","�t���[�R�[�h�P","�t���[�R�[�h�Q","�t���[�R�[�h�R","���W�S��","�_���W�S��","���n���i"
```

Content of my csv file (Japanese Shift-JIS)

```
来店店舗, 来店日, 受付No., 来店に含む, 顧客No., 顧客名, 新規, 目的, メニューコード, メニュー, 数量, 金額, 割引, 計, 担当者, 指名, 区分, 売上区分, 消費税率, 役務購入日, 契約書No., 消化担当者2, フリーコード１, フリーコード２, フリーコード３, レジ担当, 契約時レジ担当, 未渡商品
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen Because I can't share CSV file into here, so I have add image of csv file and part of test file on my question.

Comment: Thanks, but please share text per [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Why can't you share the CSV, or the code to generate it? Without that info, it's going to be guesswork, which makes it very difficult to provide a proven, satisfactory answer to your question.

Comment: @ggorlen Firstly, I don't know how to push CSV file into here so I just can share content of it @@. Secondly, my code doesn't any error in processing, it just not convert content from UTF-8 to Japanese before save.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright is just a browser automation tool. If your server sends file in JIS you can't download it with UTF.

Instead, you can do it manually before uploading data to the database with FS and [iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

const contentBuffer = fs.readFileSync('input.csv');
const utf8Content = iconv.decode(contentBuffer, 'jis');

fs.writeFileSync('output.csv', utf8Content);
```

Comment: I have tried your way but for some reason, it still shows characters as UTF-8 instead of shiftjis.
`const utf8Content = iconv.decode(contentBuffer, 'shiftjis'); console.log(utf8Content);`